# Dynamically named function call within jQuery chain

Tags: jquery, dynamic, prototype-programming

I have a similar question to [this Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969743/how-do-i-call-a-dynamically-named-method-in-javascript); but, would like to call the function in a jquery chain. Here is my pseudo code:

```js
function togglePanels(f) {
  var customchain;
  if (f == 'n') {
    customchain = $.next();
  } else {
    customchain = $.prev();
  }
  let $next_or_prev_panel = $current_panel
    .parents("div")
    .eq("2")
    .customchain("div")
    .find(".panel");
}
```

I imagine the solution will involve prototyping the jQuery library somehow?

Comment: Well, that code wouldn't work, but you could just do `customchain = f == 'n' ? "next" : "prev"; .... .eq("2")[customchain]("div").find(".panel");`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to use conditional (ternary) operator with a string to set `customchain` like:

```
customchain = f == 'n' ? 'next' : 'prev';
```

and then use it dynamically like:

```
let $next_or_prev_panel = $current_panel
    .parents("div")
    .eq("2")[customchain]("div")
    .find(".panel");
```

Comment: Thanks, you understood what I am actually trying to do.. no prototyping needed. But out of curiosity, can you point to an example of prototyping a new function within a jQuery object and calling it within a chain?

Comment: You can look into [How to call a custom function as part of a jQuery function chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42565943/how-to-call-a-custom-function-as-part-of-a-jquery-function-chain)